# Squares in $\mathbb{Q}_p^\ast$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I have a question to squares in $\mathbb{Q}_p^\ast$.
I know that $\mathbb{Q}_p^\ast\cong \mathbb{Z}\times V\times U_1$.
I do not think that it is necessary what $V$ or $U_1$ are here, but I can give more context if needed.

We write $x\in\mathbb{Q}_p^\ast$ uniquely as $x=p^nuv$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}, u\in U_1$ and $v\in V$. It is stated that $x$ is a square iff $n$ is even and $u$ is a square in $U_1$ as well as $v$ is a square in $V$.

But why is that? I see that n has to be even. But why has u and v be squares as well? Can it not happen that u and v are not squares but the product is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking ten questions won't change the answer :  $$V=  \{ a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times, a^{p-1} = 1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times / (1+p\mathbb{Z})\cong (\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p)^\times \cong \mathbf{F}_p^\times$$

Here you only need that $V$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p)^\times$ which is obvious from the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbf{F}_p, a \mapsto a+p\mathbb{Z}_p$  which is also a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \to \mathbf{F}_p^\times$.

$V \to \mathbf{F}_p^\times$ is injective because the polynomial $X^{p-1} -1$ has at most $p-1$ roots in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. That it is surjective is a consequence of Hensel lemma, or more directly that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{p^n} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a primitive $r$-th root of unity, with $r= \text{ord}(a\bmod p)$.

Finally for $p \ne 2$, $a \in 1+p \mathbb{Z}_p$ is always a square because $(1+pz)^{1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose k} p^k z^k$ converges for $|z|_p \le 1$, with the $p$-adic absolute value $|z|_p = p^{-v_p(z)}$.

Comment: But how is this answering the question. I know that we can decompose $\mathbb{Q}_p^\ast\cong \mathbb{Z}\times V\times U_1$ and that $V\cong\mathbb{F}_p^\ast$. But how do we see from the decomposition, that v and u has to be  squares?

Comment: @Cornman **homomorphism**

Comment: Which homomorphism?

Comment: Consider them all ! That's the way we understand rings and groups, using homomorphisms.

Comment: It is hard to find such homomorphism, since I do not even know for which set and why we can observe homomorphism here, to give an answer to my question.

Comment: @Cornman For any homomorphism $\varphi$, if $a = b^2$ then $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)^2$.

Comment: Yes. Is the whole point simply that we can not really mulitply v and u, since they are in different sets? And therefore they already have to be squares?

Comment: @Cornman To understand $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you really need to make it concrete, for example using the sequence definition. $a \mapsto a_n$ is an homomorphism by construction, here you need to look at  $a \mapsto a_1$. Then $a/a_1 \in 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p = U_1$.

Comment: Ok, lets be concrete. Lets take a square $x\in\mathbb{Q}_p^\ast$. Then $x=r^2$ and with $x=(\dotso, x_m,\dotso, x_1)=(\dotso, r^2_m,\dotso, r_1)$. We also know, that every $x_i=p^n\cdot v\cdot u_1$. Ah.. I think I see it now, since we multiply by coordinates.

Comment: @Cornman Let $\psi(b) = \lim_{n \to \infty} b^{p^n}$ the embedding $\mathbf{F}_p^\times \to \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.  If $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p^*, x = y^2$ then $y = p^{n} a$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*, a = (a_1,a_2,\ldots), a_1\not \equiv 0 \bmod p$,  $x = p^{2n}  (a_1^2,a_2^2,\ldots)$. Finally $v = \psi(a_1^2)= \psi(a_1)^2, u_1 = a^2/v$, $x = p^{2n} v u_1$ .

Comment: What do you mean with $\psi(b)=\lim_{n\to\infty} b^{p^n}$ Why is this "well-defined"?

Comment: @Cornman If you don't see it is then replace it by the embedding provided by Hensel lemma. In the $p$-adics $\lim_{n \to \infty} p^n = 0$.